# PHP Script stops running due to heavy load

Tags: php

I have two while loops which is diplaying data from database,but due to heavy load its stops working.

please let me know how to destroy/clear previous load on each while loop.

```
**Code Example: this is not an exact code, but take it as example**

for ($aw = 1; $aw <= 150000; $aw++) {

$sql="INSERT INTO say (cname,cno,clocation,email) VALUES ('Fin','0743208899','London','fin1991@live.com')"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);

}
```

Comment: We are not mind readers.  How can we tell you how to do anything without having a clue about what you are already doing?  There is no magic.  Be specific about what your problem is, and show us a reproducible example with code, if possible.  Please read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: [What are you actually trying to solve with this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?  If you give us context and describe your actual problem we may be able to offer a solution that doesn't stress the database so much.

Comment: Ya, this definitely sounds like an xy problem.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running 50,000 queries, build one query:

```
$rows = Array();
for( $aw=1; $aw<=50000; $aw++) $rows[] = "('Fin','0743208899','London','fin1991@live.com')";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO say (cname,cno,clocation.email) VALUES ".implode(",",$rows));
```

Comment: That would generate a gigantic string that could possibly take down the server.

Comment: Probably not the best approach to your problem then. Although, I had to do something similar in c#, if you want to port this over and try it out [link](http://www.codedementia.com/blogs/)

Comment: This is, indeed the best way to approach the problem of inserting a huge amount of data. The mysql server is much better equipped to handle a large chunk like this than individual inserts. 50,000 at once may be too much for some mysql configurations, but the concept is correct: chunk it.

Comment: I was not saying 50000 sql executions is better than breaking it up into chunks. Not what I meant. I was talking about the approach to the problem in terms where you are at a point where you suddenly need to deal with 50000 rows at once. The workload needs to be broken up into manageable chunks either in this process (like how i had to do it in the link i posted), or else across a span of time (asynchronously).

Comment: @Kolink thats not it, its when multiple requests are done like this, then you can trash the server.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I would hope that a query such as this is in a Cron task somewhere, that is called very rarely. I can't see any reason why this query would be on a regular or frequently-accessed webpage.